# How to center a ImageView at bottom background layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a header that only display a background image.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/header_bg
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

I want to add a circular image at bottom of background layout and also center circular image like this!!
[circular image at bottom background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZQn2.png)
Could anybody help me regarding this @Thanks

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` to stack views on top of each other. That way, you can align the circular image on top of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ImageView` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/header_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="{Your drawable}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```